# xcode and extracting data values from NSDictionary (objectForKey & valueForKey)

Tags: xcode, json, ios5

I am little confused about data type NSDictionary as it pertains to JSON structure and need help. Here is my JSON output:

```
{
    "requestDetails":
    {
        "timeStamp":"2001-12-17T09:30:47-08:00",
        "transactionType":"QUERY",
        "action":"GET INVOICES",
    },
    "Payload":
    {
        "event":
        {
            "sourceRecordType":"INVOICE INQUIRY",
            "serviceRecordType":"INVOICE",
            "ownershipType":"EXPLICIT",
        },
    },
    "executionDetails":
    {
        "timeStamp":"2012-12-04T13:48:21-08:00",
        "statusType":   "SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTION",
        "statusCode":"0",
        "DBRecordCount":"0",
        "processedRecordCount":"0",
        "warning":
        [
            {
                "errorCode":"257",
                "errorDescription":"Criteria specified is incorrect. Please Verify that the criteria is correct.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            },
            {   "errorCode":"60",
                "errorDescription":"No results were found.  Please enter new search criteria.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

Now my understanding is this whole thing is dictionary and objectForKey:@"executionDetails" will give the following output:

```
{
        "timeStamp":"2012-12-04T13:48:21-08:00",
        "statusType":   "SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTION",
        "statusCode":"0",
        "DBRecordCount":"0",
        "processedRecordCount":"0",
        "warning":
        [
            {
                "errorCode":"257",
                "errorDescription":"Criteria specified is incorrect. Please Verify that the criteria is correct.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            },
            {   "errorCode":"60",
                "errorDescription":"No results were found.  Please enter new search criteria.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            }
        ],
    }
```

How do I pick values within [] brackets. I tried valueForKey and ObjectForKey. I am not clear on processing structures and appreciate help

```
warning":
        [
            {
                "errorCode":"257",
                "errorDescription":"Criteria specified is incorrect. Please Verify that the criteria is correct.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            },
            {   "errorCode":"60",
                "errorDescription":"No results were found.  Please enter new search criteria.",
                "__hashCodeCalc":false
            }
        ],
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an array. You can access its contents like so.

```
NSDictionary *executionDetails = [json objectForKey:@"executionDetails"];
NSArray *warnings = [executionDetails objectForKey:@"warning"];

for (NSDictionary *warning in warnings) {
    NSLog(@"%@", warning);
}
// To access an individual warning use: [warnings objectAtIndex:0]
```

You can also use modern Objective-C syntax to make it clearer:

```
NSDictionary *executionDetails = json[@"executionDetails"];
NSArray *warnings = executionDetails[@"warning"];
NSLog(warnings[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. But Is there a place where I can go and look for help to understand objectForKey and how JSON output maps.

Comment: In this case you are not really working with JSON. The JSON has already been deserialized and you are working with either [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) or [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Otherwise I suggest consulting the documentation for whichever JSON library you are working with, e.g. [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I will refer to JSON library.